# How to use HTTP server for getting input from the client and manipulate it

Tags: python, http, server, request

I'v been using python before but never web.
I want to write a python program for generating a server that get the client input and do some function with it.
for example: a word.
And than return it's ASCII value.
I guess it's a very basic question, but I am totaly new to this stuff.

Comment: This isn't really a SO type question, but i'd check out Django or Flask if I was you.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to use `BaseHTTPServer`, check this example:

```
import BaseHTTPServer

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
    requestPath = self.path
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write("requested path: " + requestPath)


httpServer = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 80), RequestHandler)
httpServer.serve_forever()
```

Note: To run on port 80 you need permissions, so either run this with sudo or use some bigger port number (like 8080).

Comment: Thanks, I used it and what I got when I typed: http://localhost:8000/ on the browser was: requested path:/                                                                    And back to my question: I want that the user could write things in it, I will run some function on the input and return the output. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

For local development, you can play around with running a SimpleHTTPServer to receive HTTP requests:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

If you want to make a full-on web service or API that can take in input and respond to it, that sounds like a great use case for one of the Python web frameworks. I'm partial to [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/), but [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) might be a bit easier to get set up with.